# Terraform public ip output on Azure

Tags: azure, terraform

I am following the example [1] to output the public IP of a new VM created on Azure with Terraform. It works fine when creating only 1 VM, but when I add a counter (default 2), it doesn't output anything.

This is how I am modifying the .tf file:

```
variable "count" {
    default = "2"
}
...

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
  name                         = "test-pip"
  location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  public_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes      = 30

  tags {
    environment = "test"
  }
}
...

data "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
  count               = "${var.count}"
  name                = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.test.*.name, count.index)}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.test.resource_group_name}"
}

output "public_ip_address" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_public_ip.test.*.ip_address}"
}
```

After terraform apply:

```
Outputs:

public_ip_address = [
    ,

]
```

[1] https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/public_ip.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that you cannot output the multi public IPs is that you do not create multi public IPs. So when you use `${data.azurerm_public_ip.test.*.ip_address}` to output them, there no these resources for you.

For the terraform, you could add the `count` in the resource `azurerm_public_ip` to create multi public IPs and output them with `azurerm_public_ip.test.*.ip_address` like this:

```
variable "count" {
    default = "2"
}
...

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
  count                        = "${var.count}"
  name                         = "test-${count.index}-pip"
  location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  public_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes      = 30

  tags {
    environment = "test-${count.index}"
  }
}
...

output "public_ip_address" {
  value = "${azurerm_public_ip.test.*.ip_address}"
}
```

The screenshot of the result like this:

[image]

I did the test just create the public. So I change the allocation method into Static and output it with the resource.

If you want to use the `data` to reference the public IPs. The code would like this:

```
data "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
  count               = "${var.count}"
  name                = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.test.*.name, count.index)}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
}

output "public_ip_address" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_public_ip.test.*.ip_address}"
}
```

Hope this will help you. If you need more help please let me know.

Comment: I actually had count variable in public ip, but I copy-pasted it from the wrong place, sorry. In any case, changing the allocation from Dynamic to Static made it work and I can see the 2 IPs in the output. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I change the allocation from Dynamic to static just because I need the addresses to come out right and I just create public IP to test, no VMs. Anyway, if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

So I just ran into the exact same problem with my deployment into Azure.
The above solutions worked( Charles Xu's solution), with one caveat... I had to:
**hard-code the name of the resource group**, 
as well as add a **depends on clause** to the output block.

I am sure that the above answers are the correct way to go about it however the value of the resource group key in the data object "azurerm_public_ip" needed to be hardcoded...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? I have answered the question, as well as provided my understanding (with pictures)

Comment: I would give -1 for using screenshots instead of code block. No one can copy and use your solution this way. If you improve your answer I would give it +1